# How to focus on location on Google maps, considering a view is on top of it?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

### Background

Suppose I have a Google maps view, and another view on top of it, that covers a part of it, hiding some content of the map.

### The problem

I need to make the "camera" of the map, to focus and have a marker on a coordinate , yet let it all be in the middle of the visible part of the map.

Something like this:

[image]

The original code was focusing on (about) the center of the entire screen, making the marker almost invisible (as the bottom view covers it).

Thing is, I can't find the proper way to set the correct value to the Y coordinate of the map itself (meaning latitude).

### What I've tried

I tried, given the height of the bottom view, and the coordinate that I've put the marker on, to calculate the delta (yet of course not change the marker itself) :

```
    final float neededZoom = 6.5f;
    int bottomViewHeight = bottomView.getHeight();
    LatLng posToFocusOn = ...;
    final Point point = mMap.getProjection().toScreenLocation(posToFocusOn);
    final float curZoom = mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom;
    point.y += bottomViewHeight * curZoom / neededZoom;
    posToFocusOn = mMap.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(point);
    final CameraUpdate cameraPosition = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(new Builder().target(posToFocusOn).zoom(neededZoom).build());
```

Sadly, this focuses way above the marker.

### The question

What's wrong with what I wrote? What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ok, I've found a workaround, which I think works on all devices (tested on 3, each with a different screen resolution and size) :

I've measured how many pixels (and then converted to DP) a change of one degree has on the marker itself.

From this, I measured the height of each view, and calculated the delta needed to move the camera.

In my case, it's this way (supposing the zoom is 6.5f) :

```
    //measured as 223 pixels on Nexus 5, which has xxhdpi, so divide by 3
    final float oneDegreeInPixels = convertDpToPixels( 223.0f / 3.0f);
    final float mapViewCenter = mapViewHeight / 2.0f;
    final float bottomViewHeight = ...;
    final float posToFocusInPixelsFromTop = (mapViewHeight - bottomViewHeight) / 2.0f ;// can optionally add the height of the view on the top area
    final float deltaLatDegreesToMove = (mapViewCenter - posToFocusInPixelsFromTop) / oneDegreeInPixels;
    LatLng posToFocusOn = new LatLng(latitude - deltaLatDegreesToMove, longitude);
    final CameraUpdate cameraPosition = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(new Builder().target(posToFocusOn).zoom(neededZoom).build());
```

And it worked.

I wonder if it can be adjusted to support any value of zoom.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is almost right, but it goes above the marker because you are taking into account `bottomViewHeight` when computing `point.y` instead of `bottomViewHeight/2` (When your view's size is 200px, you only need to displace the map 100px to recenter it):

```
point.y += (bottomViewHeight / 2) * curZoom / neededZoom;
```

**Update:**

This is a more general approach taht takes into account the map bounds and calculates a new map bounds according to the height of your `bottomView`. This is zoom independent.

```
public void recenter() {
    LatLngBounds mapBounds = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
    Point nothEastPoint = mMap.getProjection().toScreenLocation(mapBounds.northeast);
    Point souhWestPoint = mMap.getProjection().toScreenLocation(mapBounds.southwest);

    Point newNorthEast = new Point(nothEastPoint.x, nothEastPoint.y + bottomView.getHeight() / 2);
    Point newSouhWestPoint = new Point(souhWestPoint.x, souhWestPoint.y + bottomView.getHeight() / 2);

    LatLngBounds newBounds = LatLngBounds.builder()
            .include(mMap.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(newNorthEast))
            .include(mMap.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(newSouhWestPoint))
            .build();

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(newBounds, 0));
}
```

Note that each time you call `recenter()` the map will move.

Comment: This is correct, but for some reason, it works well only if the current zoom is the same as the needed zoom (otherwise it looks a lot to the top, if the current zoom is smaller than the new zoom. I think something is wrong with the zoom too. removing the zoom calculation didn't help, as well as changing the order of them (as I thought I might have the wrong way to do it).

Comment: About "recenter", I don't understand. What to do with it? What about the various variables I've mentioned? How does it take into account the view that's on top, and the coordinate to go to?

Comment: You can call `recenter` when you show your `bottomView`. It takes into account the current zoom level (because it displaces the map bounds). The view that is on top is taken into account as is uses `bottomView.getHeight()` to recalculate the bounds. The method automatically moves the current center of the map at the current zoom to the "new" center (taking into account the view on top)

Comment: Where do I provide it the input coordinate, of where the marker is (to focus on it) ? And where can I set the zoom? Those are the input parameters... I don't understand what the function is supposed to do, without any parameters. re-center on what? After all, each point that the map shows is a center of something... :)

Comment: `recenter` centers the *current target* and the *current zoom* taking into account the `bottomView` size, so you need to do `mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder().target(posToFocusOn).zoom(neededZoom).build()));` first and then call `recenter()`. As we are using `mMap.getProjection()` which uses the current map bounds, I think it can't be done in one single step... :/

Comment: You mean to call this function right after I tell the camera to move somewhere? If so, this doesn't work, as it seems to just move the camera a bit to the south. I think it just disables the previous call to move the camera.

Comment: Yes, this is the intended behaviour. I have tested it in several situations. If this doesn't work for you could you share an example so I can correct it? Your workaround works but again, with a fixed zoom level

Comment: My workaround isn't complete, I know. There should be a more precise way to calculate the pixels-per-degree, including the zoom factor, but for now this will suffice. If you know of a better solution (not like what I wrote), that will have zoom&coordinate as the input, please let me know.